# Confusing about using angularJS with Codigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, angularjs

I'm new to front-end MVC and I decide to create a SPApplication then I found this angularJS. Of course, other MVC as well but I prefer angularJS.

Ok, my questions here.
Before this, I normally store my MVC files at backend MVC folders which is codeigniter view folder if it is html partial or page.

So is it the time to move the backend MVC to frontend?

Another question, what is codeigniterRest? do I need it to use with angularJS?

Answer (score 2):

No, the backend MVC in CodeIgniter and the frontend MVC in Angularjs have a separate role totally.

The backend MVC will handle the data sent to the app by your frontend.

The frontend MVC in angularjs will receive a response (usually in json) from the backend MVC in CI and handle that data using its views and controllers.

So your Single Page App will consist of all the bells and whistles of CI + 1 view page (or more if you break that page into partial includes) that will store the angularjs app in it.